# How to compare values of currency number formats

Tags: java, compare, number-formatting, currency-formatting

[The code in the picture returning false in both cases of comparison, what values should be given to get the true value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjYYD.png)

Comment: What does the first println output in console?

Comment: java.text.DecimalFormat@7adaa
R$ 466,56

Answer (score 0):

First of all please add code instead of image. Its hard to help with code in image.

String comparison with == may or may not return true. Use equals

So your code gives following output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale br = new Locale("pt", "BR");
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(br);
    float d = 466.56f;
    System.out.println(nf+" : "+nf.format(d));
    System.out.println(nf.format(d) == "R$ 466,56");  // will return false.
    System.out.println(nf.format(d).equals("R$ 466,56")); // compare string with equals
}
```

Output:

```
java.text.DecimalFormat@7ad2a : R$ 466,56
false
true
```

Comment: For me nf.format(d) is printing 466,56    and not R$ 466,56

Comment: Oh ok.   Edited detail. Working for me.  Please try with Code I have used

Comment: Thank you. I coppied your code but still it retruning me false and giving me decimal format: DecimalFormat@7adaa

Comment: Thank you. It's giving me true but if I re-typed the value then it's giving me false. Do you know why it's working like that

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, there is a different unicode for spaces. Unicode for the space getting while I typed is '\u0020' but NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance.format(float) method returning same string but the space is having a unicode of '\u00a0' and this unicode character is excluded from isWhitespace() method. That's why it's returning false for me.